# Automate Maven Scripts

Tags: maven

I have a series of Maven Scripts which are to be run in Linux Platform for doing Reversion and  Lableing for my Project. I would like to know what Building Tools i can use to automate the Maven Scripts in the Linux Platform?

Also say suppose I have got some error while doing the Reversioning / Lableing of the code. How can the Automate tools Handle these scenarios.

Please let me know of the effective tools and I would certainly reply back whether those do help me out or not!

Comment: What do you mean by "maven scripts." Maven itself is a build tool that automates many tasks, executed by the `mvn` script. If the command line you use for maven is more complicated than `mvn clean deploy` - would not a small shell script suffice?

Comment: Write your own tools. Consider yourself omnipotent. Why do so many people from large companies and corporations and support departments always think that the poor approaches they follow have become an open source standard? Better yet, that there are free tools that do everything for you just like you want them to...?!

Comment: Hi noahz....Of course Maven is itself a build tool...but in my project...there are many Maven Scripts which run one by one. It takes time...so wanted to automate even those scripts.Hope i have made my point understandable.

Comment: As others have mentioned, you can install a build service locally on your machine or on a sever, which runs a build every time you commit code, or overnight, or when you schedule it, etc. Have a look at https://travis-ci.org for an example used by open source projects.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest leveraging a "job" coordinator such as Jenkins or Cruise Control to manage any and all of our automation.  Maven is natively supported and understood by these tools.  An agent will reside on your server, and do the bidding of your coordinator.

Answer (score 0):

[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) is a good solution to automate maven build:

- easy to install
- easy integration with maven
- allow you to automate simple task after build failure/success like sending email
- many plugins including [this one](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task) that allow you to do more complex task after a build failure (or build success)

Answer (score 0):

Any one of this

1. Jenkins
2. Hudson
3. Atlassian bamboo
4. TeamCity

Answer (score 0):

After using LuntBuild, Jenkins and teamcity I can say without a doubt that TeamCity is by far the superior choice.
I think it's free for a small configuration (3 agents, and up to 10 build configurations).
It very easy to install and configure, compatible with most source control systems.